# Delete Image Via Radio Button

Tags: php

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've put together the script below which creates an image gallery.

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['del']))
      $originalname = intval($_POST['del']);

      $file = 'UploadedFiles/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '/' . $_SESSION['locationid'] . '/' '$originalname';
if (!unlink($file))
  {
  echo ("Error deleting $file");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("Deleted $file");
  }
?> 

<?php 

  $galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '/' . $_SESSION['locationid'] . '/';

  $thumbnailsPath = $galleryPath . 'Thumbnails/'; 

  $absGalleryPath = realpath($galleryPath) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 

  $descriptions = new DOMDocument('1.0'); 
  $descriptions->load($absGalleryPath . 'files.xml'); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
  <title>Gallery</title> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <link href="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <!--[if IE]>   
  <link href="Styles/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <![endif]-->
  <script src="Libraries/jquery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="Libraries/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

  $(function() { $('a.fancybox').fancybox(); }); 

  </script> 
  <style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 110px;
}
.style4 {font-size: 12px}
-->
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function showdialog() {
        // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:160,
            modal: false,
            buttons: {
                "Delete image": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    };
    </script>


</head>
<body style="font-family: Calibri; color:  #505050; font-size: 9px; border-bottom-width: thin; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: -476px; margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: -10px;">
<div align="right" class="style1"> <a href = "javascript:document.gallery.submit()"/> Add Images <a/> &larr; View Uploaded Images </div>
  <form id="gallery" name="gallery" class="page" action="index.php" method="post">  
  <div id="container"> 
    <div id="center"> 
      <div class="aB"> 
        <div class="aB-B"> 
          <?php if ('Uploaded files' != $current['title']) :?>
          <?php endif;?>
          <input name="deleteimage" type="button" value="Delete Selected Image" onclick="showdialog()" />
          <div class="demo"> 
            <div class="inner"> 
              <div class="container"> 
                <div class="gallery"> 
                  <ul class="gallery-image-list"> 
                  <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) : 
                          $xmlFile = $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->item($i); 
                          $name = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('originalname'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $description = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
                          $source = $galleryPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('source')); 
                          $thumbnail = $thumbnailsPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('thumbnail')); 
                  ?>
                    <li class="item"> 
                      <a class="fancybox" target="_blank" rel="original" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img class="preview" 
                        alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"  src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" /></a><?php echo "<input type='radio' name='del' value='{$originalname}' />"?></li>
                        <p><span class="style4"><b>Image Name:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('originalname'));?> <br />
                          <b>Image Description:</b> <?php echo htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'));?> </span><br />  
                          <?php endfor; ?>
                          </li>
                        </p>
                  </ul>
                </div> 
              </div> 
            </div> 

    </div> 
    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete This Image?">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>This image will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
    </div> 
        <div class="aB-a">        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
  </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Against each image, and appearing in this line of my code:  `alt="<?php echo $name; ?>"  src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>" /></a><?php echo "<input type='radio' name='del' value='{$originalname}' />"?></li>` I've added a radio button.

Upon a radio button being selected, and the 'Delete Selected Image' button being clicked I would like the image to be deleted at this filepath:

```
$galleryPath = 'UploadedFiles/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '/' . $_SESSION['locationid'] . '/';
```

and here : `$thumbnailsPath = $galleryPath . 'Thumbnails/';`

I'm not brilliant with PHP, but I've done some research and I believe that I need to use the 'unlink' command. So I thought I'd have a go at trying to write this procedure using just the one filepath initially. I can select a radio button, and get the correct `Dialog Confirmation` message to appear, but unfortunately it doesn't delete the image, and I'm not really sure where the problem lies.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps t ake a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong?

Many thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are passing the correct path to the image to the unlink command, it is possible the user account running PHP does not have write permissions on the file.

You may want to turn errors on at E_WARNING level, then run a test script to see if you get a warning. You should also test the return value of unlink, as it returns FALSE on failure.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to reply. The problem I have is that I don't receive any error message, which may suggest that the code, rather than a permission issue is the cause. But because I'm a little new to PHP, I'm not sure whether there is a problem with my code. I was really wanting confirmation, although I appreciate that this may just hyperthetical, that my code is correct or not? Kind regards

Comment: The syntax for this line is wrong, you are missing a dot to join the last two strings:  
$file = 'UploadedFiles/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '/' . $_SESSION['locationid'] . '/' '$originalname';  
vs  
$file = 'UploadedFiles/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '/' . $_SESSION['locationid'] . '/' . '$originalname';  
See the difference?

Comment: Hi @Greg, many thanks for this. I see what what you mean. I'll make the changes. Kind regards

Comment: Whoops, I forgot about one part. When you use single quotes, variables are not interpolated. You should pull the single quotes off the $originalname, as it is treating it as a string literal, and not the value of the variable.